# Why dotenv not able to load environment variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, dotenv, absolute-path

I have the following directory structure: [image]

I am using dotenv to load environment variables but its not loading them.It gives `undefined` even though I have defined them in the .env file.

The code in index.js is here:

[image]

I've even tried the following for requiring:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

`require('dotenv').config({path:'C:\Users\xuios\Desktop\AirlineManagementProject\FlightsAndSearch\src\.env'});`   // absolute path

`require('dotenv').config({path:'FlightsAndSearch\src\.env'});` //relative path

However it still doesnt load the env variables defined as :[image]

Comment: don't use \ in a string in javascript ... either double up \\ or you can use / like in a real operating system, I believe nodejs will handle the conversion for you

Comment: also, not sure why you're going up 2 levels in the picture, surely the .env file is in the current folder

Comment: @JaromandaX I even tried copying absolute and relative paths to .env file but still it couldn't load the env variables I've set.Also used '/' instead of '\' but didn't work

Comment: It lloks like your `.env` and `index.js` are in the same folder so have your tried just `require('dotenv').config();`?

Comment: @jQueeny ya tried that still didn't work

Comment: Did you `npm install dotenv` ?

Comment: @jQueeny yes I did!

Comment: Are you running the app from the parant folder? `node FlightsAndSearch/src/index.js` || `node src/index.js`? how does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: @Anuga I ran it from the src folder